# reverse geocoding using nominatim in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I'm using nominatim for reverse geocoding in my asp.net website (Visual Studio 2010, C#).

I'm getting answer in XML or json format on another webpage like below:

- [json](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=23.02951&lon=72.48689)
- [xml](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=23.02951&lon=72.48689)

I cant read this address using XML reader or HTTP response.

Need help to convert this text into plain text and displaying on my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have to deserialize json data that you got from the web Service.
You have to define two new classes, namely:

```
 [DataContract]
        public class Address
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string road { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string suburb { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string city { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string state_district { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string state { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string postcode { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string country { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string country_code { get; set; }
        }

        [DataContract]
        public class RootObject
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string place_id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string licence { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string osm_type { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string osm_id { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string lat { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string lon { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string display_name { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public Address address { get; set; }
        }
```

After that you will able to get the data by using this code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            var jsonData = webClient.DownloadData("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=23.02951&lon=72.48689");

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
            var rootObject = ser.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(jsonData));
```

**rootObject** contains all data that you need, in order to convert it to plain text or any other format.

Comment: The remote name could not be resolved: 'nominatim.openstreetmap.org'

Comment: Actually the problem is that, the specified URL do not return any response. we can redirect to that page but cant get response. Any suggestion to cop up with it???

Comment: Did you exceed the quato of the public service?

Comment: I did test it before I posted it here. Do you have a proxy server installed? If so, then you have to setup Webclient respectively.

Comment: I can redirect to that URL but can't download data. Need to setup Webclient in that case too? And what steps to follow for that?

Comment: It depends on how your network configuration... What do you mean by saying "I can redirect to that URL"?

Comment: Response.Redirect("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=23.02951&lon=72.48689"); will redirect me to that page where I'll find address in json format. But using your code I can't download that data.

Comment: It looks like that the user that is assigned to the app pool has no network access, could it be so?

Comment: I'm not able to guess why this is happening. I'll try to check this code from another computer and network. Then I'll let you know.

Comment: It is definitely something to do with your network settings/configuration.

Comment: Yes. Problem solved. Manual proxy settings were required. Thank u.

Answer (score 4):

To resolved Forbidden error i have added header with WebClient object as below-

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 

**webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");**

 var jsonData = webClient.DownloadData("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=23.02951&lon=72.48689");

DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
var rootObject = ser.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(jsonData));
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement the example given by **Vladimir Gondarev**, Nominatim currently does not accept requests without Referer and User-Agent.
That way, just add these two lines:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
webClient.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://www.microsoft.com");
```

(Modify to your liking).